# c++ гигантский массив

Tags: c++, массивы, память

Как на с++ сделать матрицу размером 10^5, у меня получается но только 10^4

Код

```
int M[100000][100000];
```

приводит к ошибке.

Comment: Т.е. 10^10 элементов? По, скажем, 4 байта? Т.е. на 40 гигабайт? Как минимум для такой адресации требуется 64-разрядная программа... А вам такой размер **точно** нужен? Что это вы такое считать хотите? Кстати, а сколько физической памяти на машине?

Comment: @Harry https://www.dropbox.com/s/tgyzi30p07je5bd/Pfa%20%28lv%29.pdf?dl=1 (там где ievaddati(входные данные) смотреть)

Comment: У вас же есть ограничение - в матрице не более 10^6 элементов (S × N ≤ 10^6) - а это всего 4 мегабайта. Чувствуете разницу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас есть два размера - S и N, причем S*N <= 10<sup>6</sup>.

Как вариант,

```
cin >> S >> N;
int ** a = new int*[S];
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) a[i] = new int[N];
```

Или еще проще:

```
cin >> S >> N;
vector<vector<int>> a(S,vector<int>(N,0));
```

И уж совсем не нужно делать матрицу, которая будет заполнена не более чем на сотую долю процента...

Да, я не очень вникал в вашу задачу, так что не знаю, нужна ли даже такая матрица, или задачу можно решить проще (все же латышский - не мой конек :)). Но даже если нужна - то она тут вполне разумного размера...

Comment: ок, спс, протестирую потом

Comment: но на всякий случай  можно попытаться перехватить  bad_alloc или  c nothrow проверять  на  ненулевость.

Comment: кст, латышский тоже не мой конёк, но блин я бы это сейчас не делал это задание 1) если бы писал не на питоне(времени не хватает и много памяти занимает) 2)если бы на компах было что-то кроме ILDE

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Да вряд ли такое выскочит, память-то небольшая... Но, понятно, не мешает :)

Comment: @Harry, я просто подумал, что раз вопрос задан, значит были проблемы(может комп слабый)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan на олимпиадах система тестирования выдаёт ограничения по времени и по памяти

Comment: Да, вряд ли там ограничение памяти в 40 гигабайт :)